# Data Format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have data as below :

Month and then corresponding units sold for 3 different item type

```
Month  Sale1 Sale2 Sale3 
1      20   
2      12
3      50
1            2
2            17
3            56
1                   11
2                   35
3                   9
```

I want data to be in below format:

```
Month  Sale1 Sale2 Sale3 
1      20    2      11  
2      12    17     35
3      50    56     9
```

Comment: Consider using `MAX`.

Comment: Could you help me with the query?

Comment: It's a simple `group by`.

Comment: *"Could you help me with the query?"* The documentation has more than enough information to help you: [MAX (Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Got It. It was very simple. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `SUM` is better then `MAX` if there can be items from one type across different months:

```
SELECT [Month]
      ,SUM(Sale1) AS Sale1
      ,SUM(Sale2) AS Sale2
      ,SUM(Sale3) AS Sale3
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [Month]
```